# Directly Scraping HTML table using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, html-table

Is there any direct way to scrape HTML table?  It would be great if we give the class of HTML table and it provides the results?

For example, I need to get table for this [URL](https://buchholz-stadtwerke.de/wasseranalyse.html)

I can use [this](https://srome.github.io/Parsing-HTML-Tables-in-Python-with-BeautifulSoup-and-pandas/) procedure but I need a clean or direct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, then try this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://buchholz-stadtwerke.de/wasseranalyse.html"

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
[                    Parameter  Einheit    Grenzwert Messwert, Februar 2020
0            Wassertemperatur       °C          NaN                     98
1         Leitfähigkeit (25°)    µS/cm         2790                    302
2   Sauerstoff (elektrochem.)     mg/l          NaN                    109
3                     pH-Wert      NaN  6,5 bis 9,5                    806
4             Sättigungsindex      NaN          NaN                    001
5         Karbonathärte (dH°)      °dH          NaN                    454
6           Gesamthärte (dH°)      °dH          NaN                    645
7                Härtebereich      NaN          NaN                  weich
8         Calcitlösekapazität     mg/l            5                    -01
and so on...
```

Also, this spits out a `.csv` file with the data from the table.

EDIT:

This sort of feels like a hack, but it works. Based on the comment and the URL, you can loop over the tables from the `df` and split them up in separate files.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.swd-ag.de/energie-wasser/wasser/trinkwasseranalyse/"

df = pd.read_html(io=requests.get(url).text, flavor="bs4")
for index, table in enumerate(df, start=1):
    table.to_csv(f"table_{index}.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Is there any way to define the table separately? I have also pages where there are 2 tables

Comment: Can you share the url to the page with two tables?

Comment: For example, here are many tables `https://www.swd-ag.de/energie-wasser/wasser/trinkwasseranalyse/`

Comment: I've updated the answer. See if that's what you wanted.

Comment: That's working but it would be great if we could define the class of table. But I am happy with the results, Thanks again!

Comment: You could use the `id` of the `table` tag but for the page you shared all tables have the same `id`, which is `table_175690`.